# TSQL query xml output

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a query that I am running for some search results on my page. The stored procedure looks like this:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM   (SELECT id,
                   data,
                   dataType,
                   dataLocation,
                   tag,
                   whoAdded,
                   whenAdded,
                   notes,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY data ORDER BY whenAdded DESC) AS rn
            FROM   Tags_Accounts
            WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                           FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags))) AS a
    WHERE  rn = 1
    FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
END
END
```

This will go through my records that looks like the following:

[image]

Now, If I were to search for the tag stuff, paypal it should return 2 results as the partition is on the data column.

The XML output is as follows for  the results:

```
            <root>
              <results>
                <id>43</id>
                <data>123333</data>
                <dataType>1</dataType>
                <dataLocation>AF</dataLocation>
                <tag>paypal</tag>
                <whoAdded>chussey</whoAdded>
                <whenAdded>2013-11-22T11:01:50.117</whenAdded>
                <rn>1</rn>
              </results>
              <results>
                <id>41</id>
                <data>12345</data>
                <dataType>1</dataType>
                <dataLocation>AF</dataLocation>
                <tag>paypal</tag>
                <whoAdded>chussey</whoAdded>
                <whenAdded>2013-11-22T10:59:39.277</whenAdded>
                <rn>1</rn>
              </results>
              <results>
                <id>50</id>
                <data>RGG</data>
                <dataType>2</dataType>
                <dataLocation>AF</dataLocation>
                <tag>stuff</tag>
                <whoAdded>chussey</whoAdded>
                <whenAdded>2013-11-22T22:25:41.393</whenAdded>
                <rn>1</rn>
              </results>
            </root>
```

It included the 2 results for PayPal as the data was different in the data col. It returned 1 record for stuff as the data was already found matching in the results for the tag PayPal.

My question: is there any way to do exactly what it's doing now but in the `<Tag></Tag>` include all of the tags that match the data in the data column?

For example, because the tag `stuff` was found with the other tag `Paypal` it would include them together.

The goal out of this is to find any data that contains the tag searched. If its found and there are more than 1 tag for that piece of data, it will include all the tags with it.

```
<results>
    <id>50</id>
    <data>RGG</data>
    <dataType>2</dataType>
    <dataLocation>AF</dataLocation>
    <tag>stuff, testing</tag>
    <whoAdded>chussey</whoAdded>
    <whenAdded>2013-11-22T22:25:41.393</whenAdded>
    <rn>1</rn>
</results>
```

Comment: Where does that `testing` in your desired output's `<tag>` come from? Can't see it anywhere in your original output ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is doing what you want:

```
WITH OrderedTags
AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            data,   
            dataType,
            dataLocation,
            CAST(tag as NVARCHAR(max)) as tag,
            whoAdded,
            whenAdded,
            notes,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY data ORDER BY tag, id) AS rn
    FROM    Tags_Accounts T
)
,RecurseTags (data, tags, rn)
AS
(
--Anchor
    SELECT  data,
            tag as tags,
            rn
    FROM    OrderedTags T
    WHERE   rn = 1
    UNION ALL
--Recurse
    SELECT  R.data,
            tags + N', ' + tag,
            T.rn
    FROM    RecurseTags R
    JOIN    OrderedTags T
        ON  T.data = R.data
        AND T.rn = R.rn + 1
)
,CommaSeparatedTags(data, tags)
AS
(
    SELECT  data, tags
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  data,
                tags,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY data ORDER BY rn DESC) AS rn
        FROM    RecurseTags
    ) T
    WHERE rn = 1
)
,RequiredRows
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT  A.id,
            A.data, 
            A.dataType,
            A.dataLocation,
            C.tags as tag,
            A.whoAdded,
            A.whenAdded,
            A.notes,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.data ORDER BY A.whenAdded DESC) AS rn
    FROM   OrderedTags A
    JOIN   dbo.splitstring (@tags) T
        ON T.Value = A.tag
    JOIN    CommaSeparatedTags C
        ON C.data = A.data) A
    WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT * FROM RequiredRows
FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
```

Basically, it orders the tags by data, generates a consolidated table, and then joins your original query to that...

Comment: This looks pretty good and I think it will work however I am getting an error "Invalid column name 'Value'" during the join

Comment: Fixed it by changing that to Name instead. This works perfect!! I would have never got this myself, thanks so much for taking the time to read it and provide the code - life saver!